# wordpress: domain mapping and site URL display

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting, base-url, domain-mapping

i am a wordpress newbie and have not much experience with their settings. Basically, i have recently set up a domain mapping for an existing wordpress site that i took over and that i had to move to another host, so domain mapping seemed to be an easy option to point the old URL to the new host. I have set up the domain mapping to point to the new site from:

http://www.myOldExample.com 
to the new one:
http://www.myNewWebsite.com/foldername

So far the content migration worked in wordpress. The problem is that when i type in the old URL in the browser, it redirects the old page and shows the new site for the main home section as expected, but for all the subsequent links such as About, Contact, Products etc. it shows the new URL with the subfolder path, whereas i would like them to display the old URL as the base URL, so i am not sure if i need to change anything on the domain mapping site, or does this need to be done on the wordpress side? Does wordpress offer something like a base URL rewrite? I could only find in the general settings the Site URL and Wordpress URL, but i am not sure if changing those values to point to the old URL would break the site.

Many thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is url problem. When you are migrating wordpress site from one server to another server or same server but different folder, so its create url problem like http: //theoldserver to, for example, http: //thenewserver.com is problematic. So download file from this [site](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) and put this file, where blog files placed on server. Then do step, which define on this [url](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

This is very handy tool
[Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script" tool that's very handy](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) (make sure to read the instructions and have a backup of the db before using it).